# Why is my program showing this error?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been looking at it for one hour and I can't figure out why it keeps telling me the same error.
For those who wonder what my program is, basically it reads a text file which contains barcodes,name and price. Then, I will read another text file which contains only barcodes, and print its respective name and price.
Unfortunately, it only prints one line and then shows this error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 99, Size: 99
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.Search(JavaApplication9.java:66)
    at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.main(JavaApplication9.java:85)
```

main

```
public class JavaApplication9 
{
    long value1;
    String value2;
    double value3;
    ArrayList<String> toBeSplit = new ArrayList(); 
    String[] split;
    ArrayList <Inventory> productList = new ArrayList<> ();
    ArrayList <Long> barcodes = new ArrayList ();

    public long ReadFile(String sfile) throws IOException 
            {       
                int x = 0;
                File inFile = new File(sfile);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
                String sline = null;
                while ((sline=reader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        toBeSplit.add(x,sline);
                        x++;
                    }
                reader.close();  
                return inFile.length();
            }

    public void splitString ()
    {   
        int a = 0;
        while (a<toBeSplit.size())
        {
            split = toBeSplit.get(a).split(",");            
            value1 = Long.parseLong(split[0]);
            value2 = split[1];
            value3 = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
            productList.add(new Inventory (value1,value2,value3,split[0]));
            a++;
        }
    }

     public long readBarcodes (String file) throws IOException 
            {       
                File text = new File(file);
                int x = 0;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text));
                String line = null;
                while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        long barcod = Long.parseLong (line);
                        barcodes.add(x,barcod);
                        x++;
                    }
                reader.close();  
                return text.length();
            }

     public void Search()
     {
         int size = barcodes.size();
         int counter = 0;
         for (Inventory e : productList)
            {
                if ((e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0) && counter <= size)
                {
                    System.out.println (e.getRBarcode()+ "\t" + e.getName() + "\t"+ e.getPrice());
                }
                else
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        try
        {
            JavaApplication9 instance = new JavaApplication9 ();
            instance.ReadFile("Products (1).csv");
            instance.splitString();
            instance.readBarcodes("Items.txt");
            instance.Search();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print ("Error");
        }
    } 
}
```

inventory class

```
public class Inventory
{
    long barcode;
    String name,realBar;
    double price;

   public Inventory (long bars,String pname,double prices,String realBarcode)
    {
        barcode = bars;
        name = pname;
        price = prices;
        realBar = realBarcode;   
    }

    public long getBarcode ()
    {
        return barcode;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRBarcode()
    {
        return realBar;
    }

    public double getPrice ()
    {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like an `Off-by-One` error

Comment: The error message actually tells you all the details necessary to find the exact location of the problem. The program tries to access an element one behind the last, and it happens in line 66 in file `JavaApplication9.java`

Answer (score 0):

From the error, we see that you are trying to access the index `99` of an Arraylist with only `99` items. Remember that the index starts at `0`, so you can only get up to `98` before you are "Out of Bounds" (which will give you the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you saw above.)

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` tells us that this line is the culprit:

```
if ((e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0) && counter <= size)
```

`counter` starts at `0` which is good, but you are allowing `counter` to get to `size` which is `99` because you have nothing limiting it. Once `counter` reaches `99`, you try to do `barcodes.get(counter)` which will of course give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because `99` is out of bounds for `barcodes`.

Try adding a preventive if-statement inside your for loop, before everything else, to `break` when counter gets too high:

```
for (Inventory e : productList)
{
    if (counter == size)
        break;
    if ((e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0) && counter <= size)
    {
        System.out.println (e.getRBarcode()+ "\t" + e.getName() + "\t"+ e.getPrice());
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to modify your if-statement. If you change `<=` to `<`, and then rearrange the order in which the statements are evaluated, you can prevent this Exception:

```
if (counter < size && (e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0))
```

In this case, once the counter reaches `99`, it will evaluate false on `counter < size`, and because of the double-ampersand (`&&`), the second half of the if-statement will not be evaluated, so it will continue to the else-statement.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Or just change `counter <= size` to just `counter < size`

Comment: @Takendarkk I don't think that would work, because if counter reaches 99, the first if-statement will return false, so it will go to the else which just adds 1 to counter. Once the loop continues again, it will try to do barcodes.get(counter) inside the if-statement again, and will once again throw an Exception. You would also have to rearrange the if-statement for that change to work. I edited my answer to include this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your `Search` method when you say `barcodes.size()` you get the actual size.

Now, the `counter` is zero based and inside your `for` loop you are doing `barcodes.get(counter)` which actually goes till the `barcodes` size + 1. Also, `counter <= size` kind of let it hit that value.

So, all you need to do here is change

`if ((e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0) && counter <= size)`

to

`if (counter < size && (e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0))`

Answer (score 0):

In your `Search` method `barcodes.size()` gives you actual size of `ArrayList`.
But, your counter is starting from `0`.
Hence, try changing

```
if ((e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0) && counter <= size)
```

to:

```
if ((counter < size) && (e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0))
```

Comment: You would also have to switch the order of the two evaluations or else the barcodes.get(counter) would be evaluated first. If counter was 99, first the if-statement would try (e.getBarcode() - barcodes.get(counter) == 0) which includes barcodes.get(counter), and that would throw an Exception, so the other half of the if-statement would never be evaluated and is useless. Switching their order fixes this.